# why return undefined in simple condition even variabes already assigned in browser console

Tags: javascript

I know undefined is a property of the global object.

> A variable that has not been assigned a value is of type undefined.

But I wonder why i get undefined of assigned values in a `if else` condition.
Here is my code

```
var a;
var b;

a =5
b =10;

if((b>a))
  console.log("a is greater than b")
else  
  console.log("b is greater than a")
```

and I get

```
undefined
b is greater than a
```

why it return `undefined` first even both variable is already assigned

Comment: Where/how/when are you seeing this `undefined`? Are you just typing this into your console?

Comment: @deceze yea i see in my console

Comment: If you are ***typing*** this into your console, then the `undefined` is simply the result of the `if` statement (obviously the statement itself returns nothing). The console immediately evaluates all statements and shows you their value; `if` results in `undefined`. That does not mean that any part of your code is producing `undefined`; in fact, your code isn't *outputting* anything besides the two `console.log` statements, so it *can't* be outputting `undefined`.

Comment: @deceze So , JS is the crazy language . I got downvotes when i want to know the js crazy behavior .

Comment: It's not JS, it's the specific way in which you run this JS. If you save this code to a file and run it there's no `undefined` anywhere. The downvotes are mainly because you omit this fact from the question entirely, which makes it invalid/irreproducible/not generally applicable/anyone's guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only issue is that you're executing this in an interactive console. The console immediately evaluates every expression and shows you its value. This is so you can experiment and immediately see each result. The console prints a return value for *every single line*, **even if that line has no return value.**

If you type `'aaa'`, this expression evaluates to the value `'aaa'`, which the console will show you immediately. The expression `40 + 2` results in the value `42` being printed. The statement `if (true);` results in no value (`if` is not an expression and returns no value), so `undefined` is printed.

[image]

*That's* where your `undefined` comes from; not from anywhere within your code.

Answer (score -3):

In javascript, you have to write every snippet as a function. Otherwise, every snippet will return undefined, Look at the below code

```
if(true){}
```

Even this will return undefined;
Make sure you follow JS best practices.

Better rewrite the code as below,

```
 function check(a,b){
    if(a > b){
      return 'a is greater than b';
    }else { 
      return 'b is greater than a';
    }
 }
 console.log(check(1,2));
```

Revert to me if you need more clarifications.

Happy coding!!

Comment: you mean in js that `true` is `undefined` ?

Comment: yup, if u didn't return anything in js, by default it will return undefined

Comment: `true` is not `undefined`. *The result of* `if ..` is `undefined` (because `if` is a statement, not an expression which returns a value). That does *not* mean you need to write everything as expression somehow.

Comment: even i told the same, if you didnt returned anything in JS , by default it will return undefined @deceze.

Comment: @deceze its better to write every snippet inside expression will make your code the best,

Comment: 1) At some point you *cannot* make everything an expression, because not everything is an expression in Javascript. The `if` *inside* your function is not an expression, wrapping it in a function doesn't change that. 2) Unless you need the function, there's no real need to create one. If you have a good reason to create a function, do it. A dogmatic "everything should be an expression" is *not* a good reason to create lots of functions.